# React table getting issue TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-table

Since today morning we are getting below issue, After building latest node_modules :

**methods.js?ab36:59 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

at ReactTable.getDataModel (methods.js?ab36:59)

Comment: Full Error details :
methods.js?ab36:59 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at ReactTable.getDataModel (methods.js?ab36:59)
    at ReactTable._class (lifecycle.js?aa71:18)
    at ReactTable._class (methods.js?ab36:27)
    at new ReactTable (index.js?370e:30)
    at constructClassInstance (VM376323 react-dom.development.js:14204)
    at updateClassComponent (VM376323 react-dom.development.js:18413)
    at beginWork$1 (VM376323 react-dom.development.js:20186)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (VM376323 react-dom.development

Comment: Please edit the question with the full error details, including proper formatting. It's much easier to read that way.

Comment: show a piece of failed code

Answer (score 27):

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTc2J.jpg)

You should do something like this:

```
useTable({ columns, data: tableData }) // must be data
```

Comment: **We don't allow images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**. Please post your answer as ([formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) code only. To understand why, check out [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) on the [meta] site. Though it focuses on the perspective of asking questions, it also applies to answers as well.

Comment: Aaarrrggghh, this has cost me days - thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Look at this: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/1686
and try a downgrade.

P.S. Please be more accurate on your questions

Answer (score 0):

I had this error. In my case, the fix was much simpler than those suggested the above. React-table MUST be given a list. My fetch (GET request) was returning an object which I did not anticipate. React-table needs a list to iterate over, NOT an object. An array/list of objects is a list.

The fix was to use [ ] around the fetched object because this made it a list of a single object. React-table could then iterate over this list.

For example, React-table can't iterate over the following object:

{key1:pair1}

But it CAN iterate over this similar array containing one object, notice the square brackets:

[{key1:pair1}]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).